# Need help configuring IIS to serve 2.0 web services

Tags: asp.net, iis, configuration

I am attempting to deploy an ASP.NET 2.0 Web service application on an IIS server that currently serves a large .NET 1.0 web application.

I have set up an appropriate virtual directory and have set the ASP.NET version for the virtual directory to 2.0, when I attempt to browse the site in a web-browser, I am prompted for a password. If I set the ASP.NET version down to 1.0, I am not prompted for a password, but obviously receive a full application error.

How can I configure IIS so that I can have the .NET 2.0 version selected without requiring the password prompt?

I have anonymous access enabled and have the "Authenticated Access" set to integrated windows authentication"

Any help or suggestions is appreciated...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a few things.

1. Ensure that you have a separate application pool that you are running this under
2. Ensure that the proper user account has permission to the directory that your web services are located.  (Typically this is the network service account)
3. If this is still an issue after this, test another .NET 2.0 app, if you get issues try reparing or re-installing ASP.NET via the aspnet_regiis.exe app.